Backend JavaScript file EmailJS send error
I'm trying to make a route for my backend javascript express server server.js which will send an email using EmailJS to my gmail account when called.
If I try this code:

const SMTPClient = require("emailjs")

app.post('/emailContactFormSubmission', async (req, res) => {
  const { body, email } = req.body;
  console.log('Contact form submission received:');
  console.log('Body:', body);
  console.log('Email:', email);

  try {
    const client = new SMTPClient({
      user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
      password: 'abcd abcd abcd abcd', // myemail@gmail.com' app password
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      ssl: true,
    });

    const message = await client.sendAsync({
      text: 'i hope this works',
      from: '',
      to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
      cc: '',
      subject: 'testing emailjs',
    });

    console.log('message = ', message);
    res.sendStatus(200);

  } catch (err) {
    console.error('send email err: ', err);
    res.sendStatus(400);
  }


});


The server fails immediately when I run it with node server.js
> node .\server.js
C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\aws-react-docker-ghactions\server.js:125
const SMTPClient = require("emailjs")
                   ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\aws-react-docker-ghactions\node_modules\emailjs\email.js from C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\aws-react-docker-ghactions\server.js not supported.
Instead change the require of email.js in C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\aws-react-docker-ghactions\server.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\aws-react-docker-ghactions\server.js:125:20) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Node.js v20.15.0

If I change the import line to:
const SMTPClient = require("@emailjs/browser")

My node server launches correctly, but once the route is hit, there's a different error:
> node .\server.js
setSecrets()
isLocal= true
Secrets set successfully      
Server is running on port 3030
Contact form submission received:
Body: a
Email: adam@joe.omc
send email err:  TypeError: SMTPClient is not a constructor
    at C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\aws-react-docker-ghactions\server.js:135:20

Am I using the EmailJS package correctly? How can I get the send email functionaltiy working with my gmail address, so when the server.js route is hit, it sends an email to my account myemail@gmail.com

@emailjs/browser and emailjs packages are different things from different companies.
P.S. the word "browser" indicates that this is not for node.js.

The package you're trying to use is an ES Module. To use it in CommonJS (files that use require(), import it this way):
const SMTPClient = await import("emailjs");

Alternatively, switch to ESM yourself. It's the future and more and more packages will switch to this format.

Editing my code to use const SMTPClient = await import("emailjs"); inside the route, but still resulting in an error message send email err:  TypeError: SMTPClient is not a constructor

nevermind this was the right path to fix. thanks

Use this const {SMTPClient} = require('emailjs')
since to use the SMTPClient from the emailjs package with CommonJS syntax, you should import it using curly braces, similar to the ES6 module import shown in the official guide.
